# Laravel. Mysql. Ошибка при миграции

Tags: mysql, laravel, миграция

Текст ошибки:

`could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = DBsql and table_name = migrations)`

Сил нету. Лечил уже ВСЕМ что находил в сети - устанавливал разного рода-вида `apt-get install`. Или даже переустанавливал контейнер.

Надеюсь на помощь опытных програмистов.

Спасибо!

Comment: Это помогло? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329302/laravel-error-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Ответ крылся в файле `.env`. Я создал override конфиг, который записывал `.env` файл с внешнего файла при запуске контейнер. НО! Когда в конейнере поднимался сам `Laravel`, он перезаписывал `.env` из того, что было внутри. Проще говоря, я `.enviroment` настроил внутри самого `Laravel` и всё пошло.